# Applying image hover effect to the whole container

Tags: jquery, hover, gallery, fadein

How can I apply this hover effect to all the images in this container, when I hover the container?

http://www.photoshop-plus.co.uk/2012/05/21/jquery-color-fade-hover-effect/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.grey").hover(
    function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li>
<img src="images/01_grey.gif" class="grey" />
<img src="images/01_color.gif" class="color" />
</li>

<li>
<img src="images/02_grey.gif" class="grey" />
<img src="images/02_color.gif" class="color" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also make sure you read the FAQ stackoverflow.com/faq because this question isn't one which you should be asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you implement it: http://jsfiddle.net/xEuD7/

Do note you need to implement the **CSS** and **import the JavaScript plugin** into your page!

```
.gallery li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
}
img.grey {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
img.color {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.grey").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).parents('.gallery').find("img.grey").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parents('.gallery').find("img.grey").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Have all open in Dreamweaver, it works thanks. But how it is possible to do the hover effect to all images in the gallery, when hover the ul?

Comment: This is absolutely great! Thanks a lot Samuel!